# Factoring bivariate quadratics with real coefficients (for high school students).

Tags: polynomials, education

I was tutoring a Year 10 student last night (he's learning about quadratics). Unfortunately, we ran into a class of problems that I couldn't explain how to solve (beyond simply guessing and checking), and this bothered me somewhat.

**Some background.**

My argument was that to factorize $ax^2+bx+c$, you probably shouldn't sit there "guessing and checking." After all, who wants to have to *actually think* when there's a relatively simple formula available? Unless the answer suggests itself to you immediately, I argued that you should immediately go ahead and use the following theorem (which is basically the quadratic formula), since:

- it solves the problem with utter reliability, and
- you don't have to think very much, and
- it doesn't rely on the original problem being "rigged" so as to admit a simple solution.

> **Factorization Theorem for Univariate Quadratics With Real Coefficients**
>
> Given $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $P \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ satisfying $P = ax^2 + bx+c$, we have:
>
> If $\Delta(P) < 0$, then $P$ is irreducible.
>
> If $\Delta(P) \geq 0$, then $$P = a\left(x - \frac{-b-\Delta^{1/2}}{2a}\right)\left(x-\frac{-b+\Delta^{1/2}}{2a}\right)$$
>
> (Where $\Delta(P)$ is the discriminant, which, at this level, is best *defined* as $b^2-4ac$.)

Of course, this is merely the "quadratic formula theorem" in a thinly-veiled disguise. However, I prefer the above version; its easier to teach, easier to use, and more "algebraic" in nature. Anyway, to cut a long story short, I taught that:

- to factorize $ax^2+bx+c$, use the above theorem.
- to solve the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$, first factorize the LHS, and then to use the null-factor law to extract your solutions. (Hopefully, he will eventually notice that certain steps can be omitted, and thereby "discover" the quadratic formula himself; in any event, I plan not to teach it directly.)

**The conundrum.**

The student's book also had some bivariate problems, like:

> **Exercise.** Factorize $x^2+2x+1-y^2$.

These problems were always rigged so as to admit an ad-hoc solution. For example:

$$x^2+2x+1-y^2 = (x+1)^2-y^2 = (x+1-y)(x+1+y)$$

However, I wanted to teach something more systematic than all this. Searching the internet for theorems/algorithms to this effect was surprisingly fruitless; everything I found either didn't address the problem directly, or else it was written at a level I didn't understand.

> **Question.** What theorems are available to factorize bivariate quadratics with real coefficients?
>
> Let me be more specific. Assume that we're trying to factorize $$P = ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f$$
>
> I'm interested in theorems of the form: assuming certain coefficients are either $0$ or $1$,
>
> - $P$ is/isn't irreducible iff...
> - $P$ can be factorized as...
> - By making the following substitution, $P$ can be rewritten in the following, more easily factorized form...

Since students at this level have not encountered $\mathbb{C}$, hence complex numbers must be avoided. On the other hand, I have done my best to explain "formal" polynomials, so $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ is definitely on the table.

Comment: It's equation of second order curve (ellipse, hyperbola, parabola). We may use well-known methods for simplification of this equation.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza, where does one learn this stuff? I'm not sure what to search for, or which books to look in, or which articles to read. Note also that $P$ isn't an equation, its a polynomial.

Comment: In any book about analytic geometry and conic section, I suppose

Comment: You may use strightforward method: let $P = (c_1 x + c_2 y + c_3)(d_1 x + d_2 y + d_3)$ and solve a system.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza, that's just guess-and-check though. The idea is to be systematic.

Comment: Solving of equations is systematic. Even if they are non-linear.

Comment: Just as a tangent, keep in mind the *point* of the multivariate exercises is likely to get the student to recognize special-case factoring situations (namely: perfect square binomials, differences of squares, sums/differences of cubes) in nature. Pattern recognition is important! Seeing form is important! Probably the best approach for general multivariate cases (which aren't toy problems designed to have special-case-factoring solutions) that balances systematic and accessible, is to start off with Michael's approach. Them's the brakes.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza, please elaborate. How do you propose to solve equations obtained in this way systematically, and where did you learn this technique?

Comment: @goblin, I completely misunderstood your word „systematic“. It seems to me that for you it's synonym of „in one step“ or „with doing anything“. Anyway, theory of conic sections is answer to your question (because you allowed to use only linear combinations, which are affine transformations).

Comment: @MichaelGaluza, all I mean by "systematic" is that there's a deterministic process you can follow that always gets you the right answer eventually. For example, Gaussian elimination counts as a "systematic procedure." It sounds like I'll have to read up about conic sections.

Comment: @goblin: *Michael*'s method works if $P$ is factorizable because it is quadratic and that is the only non-trivial factorization form. For higher degree there will be more possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Given $a x^2 + b xy + c y^2 + d x + e y + f = 0$:

[Complete the square to get rid of the $xy$ term.]

$( 2a x + b y )^2 - b^2 y^2 + 4a ( c y^2 + d x + e y + f ) = 0$.

Let $z = 2a x + b y$.

Then $z^2 + (4ac-b^2) y^2 + 2d z + (4ae-2bd) y + 4af = 0$.

[Complete the squares.]

$(4ac-b^2) (z+d)^2 + ( (4ac-b^2) y + (2ae-bd) )^2 = (4ac-b^2) (4af+d^2) + (2ae-bd)^2$.

[If the right-hand expression is zero, we can immediately factorize.]

[Either way, we immediately can classify into the type of conic.]

Comment: I understand half the answer. I think you replace dependence on $x$ with dependence on $z$ in such a way that the coefficient of the "mixed term" $yz$ in the resulting polynomial becomes $0$. The next step makes little sense to me. If you could elaborate on how it is obtained, that would be nice. Also, note that what I really want is a factorization of $P$, not a formula for the solutions to $P=0$. I'm sure its possible to reverse-engineer the factorization given the solutions, but it would be better to answer the question as-posed rather than answering a closely-related but distinct question.

Comment: @goblin: Do you know what is completing the square? Given $ax^2 + bx + c$ one can rewrite as $a(x+?)^2+?$ to get a constant times a square plus constant with respect to $x$. In my answer I multiplied first so that there is no division involved, which means it works in generalized settings like rings. So after getting rid of the $xy$ term by grouping as I did, I just completed the square to get rid of both the $x$ and $y$ terms, each one absorbed into a square term. It leaves constant terms that I collect on the right.

Comment: @goblin: Also, I did answer the question completely; it tells you exactly when it can be factorized, namely when the expression I point out is zero. That case is a degenerate conic consisting of two lines. All other cases cannot be factorized but the shape is immediately obvious from the sign of $(4ac-b^2)$.

Comment: What do we call the expression $4ac-b^2$ or its negative? I suppose this isn't simply called "the discriminant"...

Comment: @goblin: I also didn't know what it is called, but surprisingly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section calls its negative the discriminant. Well clearly there are many different meanings of "discriminant"!

Comment: Cool thanks. Good to know that the terminology is a bit screwy ahead of time :)